# Web scraping, can't get a server response

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, timeout, axios

As you could see in the title, I have an issue with axios (Nodejs).
I try to scrape an url but the timeout answers is everytime exceed.
I've also tried with wget, same result but with curl I get the body like I want.
I'm lost about it, if you have any idea, I'm listening.
Thanks by advance.

Here is my code :

```
let axios = require('axios');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');

const A = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Host': 'www.logic-immo.com',
        'Referer': 'http://www.logic-immo.com',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
    },
    timeout : 10000
});

A.get('http://www.logic-immo.com')
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 200) {
        const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
    }
    }, (error) => console.log(err) );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit your post and include a snippet with your code? Screenshots are usually not a good way to share it and it will be easier for everyone :)

Comment: I just tried it and it is working. Is it working now? Are you sure you were not (temporarily) banned because you visited too much or something? what `curl` command are you running?

Comment: I use the basic curl command, as i said it work with curl but not with wget or axios. I've never had a response from the server so i don't know if i'm banned or not.